# Android: Replace CountDownTimer With Sleepable Alternative

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have a written an app that collects and stores geolocation lat/lons at 10 second intervals. I also have a text widget on the screen that I update as the seconds countdown. I currently use the CountDownTimer as the mechanism to time when I call the geolocation lat/lon collection and update routines.

new CountDownTimer(msUntilEnd, tickInterval);

I have many issues with the above approach. However, the biggest challenge is this. I want to continue to collect and store geolocation lat/lon when the phone is asleep because, the phone will still be moving even though it's in a pocket or a purse. However when the phone is asleep CountDownTimer doesn't continue counting down. (I get it, CountDownTimer is not intended to keep counting when the phone is asleep). Because it stops counting down, my geolocation stops collecting when the phone is asleep.

I want to replace CountDownTimer with an approach that will keep counting down while the phone is asleep. Would it work to check the number of millis have elapsed from a long int UTC from timestamp? During sleep?

I have intentionally not posted all of my code here because I am not trying to fix a syntax problem. I am seeking an approach that is an alternative to CountDownTimer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doing anything at 10-second intervals while the device is otherwise attempting to be in sleep mode is extremely bad for battery life.

Comment: Thanks. I can easily extend the interval. Is there an alternative approach to countdown timer that continues while the phone is asleep?

Comment: You can use `AlarmManager` and `JobScheduler`, but you will not necessarily be able to get location fixes very quickly when you get control, as the location subsystem will hopefully have powered down in the meantime. Plus, on Android 8.0+, you cannot get locations very frequently while in the background, by any means.

Comment: I have been reading about Android 8.0. What is the definition of "Background?" Does this mean a service that is not attached to an activity/the-UI? Does "Background" also include a an activity associated with a UI that is in Doze mode? In Doze mode on 8.0 an activity can get as many location calls as needed? But putting the location fixes in a service will limit the number of calls?

Comment: "What is the definition of "Background?"" -- see the first set of bullet points on [this page](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background-location-limits.html) and possibly [the material in this section](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background.html#services). The bullets in the first link should apply, as that is the page documenting this new limitation. With regards to the rest of your questions, I have no idea, sorry.